# Adding element twice into Linux kernel double linked list

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, linux-kernel

I am trying to use linux kernel doubly linked-list implementation mentioned in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h in user-space which its user-space implementation can be found in https://gist.github.com/roychen/1710968

following is the code which I used at first and it works fine :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

struct Node
{
    int data;
    char name[10];
    struct list_head mylist;
};

int main()
{
    LIST_HEAD(plist);

    struct Node node1 = {.data = 10, .name = "node1", .mylist = LIST_HEAD_INIT(node1.mylist)};
    struct Node node2;

    node2.data = 20;
    strcpy(node2.name, "node2");
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&node2.mylist);

    list_add_tail(&node1.mylist, &plist);
    list_add_tail(&node2.mylist, &plist);

    struct Node* iter;

    list_for_each_entry(iter, &plist, mylist)
    {
        printf("name = %s, data = %d\n", iter->name, iter->data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output of the above code is

```
name = node1, data = 10
name = node2, data = 20
```

which is as expected.

now assume that I want to add `node1` **twice**

Scenario number 1:

```
    list_add_tail(&node1.mylist, &plist);
    list_add_tail(&node1.mylist, &plist);
```

output 1:

```
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
name = node1, data = 10
... -> non-stopping loop (to infinity)
```

Scenario number 2:

```
    list_add_tail(&node1.mylist, &plist);
    list_add_tail(&node2.mylist, &plist);
    list_add_tail(&node1.mylist, &plist);
```

output 2:

```
name = node1, data = 10 (-> just one node is added to the list instead of 3 nodes)
```

The above outputs show that the list.h implementation has bug, at least in one of its function macros.

I don't know where is the bug which we cannot add a node **twice** in the linked list.

Any idea?! :|

***** **EDIT** *****
Scenario 3:

```
    list_add_tail(&node1.mylist, &plist);
    list_add_tail(&node2.mylist, &plist);
    list_add_tail(&node1.mylist, &plist);

    struct Node* iter;

    list_for_each_entry_reverse(iter, &plist, mylist)
    {
        printf("name = %s, data = %d\n", iter->name, iter->data);
    }
```

output 3:

```
name = node2, data = 20
name = node1, data = 10
name = node2, data = 20
name = node1, data = 10
name = node2, data = 20
name = node1, data = 10
name = node2, data = 20
name = node1, data = 10
name = node2, data = 20
name = node1, data = 10
... -> non-stopping loop (to infinity)
```

Comment: This is not a bug in Linux.  It's a bug in your program where you expect that the same piece of memory can appear more than once in a list without creating a cycle.

Comment: @paddy can u explain more?

Comment: @paddy so why in the second scenario, node2 is removed (which I allocate a special memory for that)?!

Comment: The next pointer for a single element in the list can only point to one location, but when you add it twice, it needs to point to two different locations at the same time (which it can't do).  What you see are side-effects of this intrinsic limitation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler your explanation is somewhat convincing but I am not satisfied completely. This is not intrinsic in loosing a part of a memory with doubly linked-list implementation

Comment: Consider which is more likely — (1) hundreds, if not thousands or millions, of Linux hackers have used the doubly-linked list mechanism without finding the problem that you suddenly came across, but they were all wrong and should have noticed what you found, or (2) you are misusing a well-tested and known-to-work-when-not-abused system. On the whole, I think it's more likely you've made a mistake than that everyone else has. Sorry, but in circumstances similar to this, the chance that everyone else is wrong is slim to negligible. It's almost (but not quite) invariably something you're doing.

Comment: You might observe the comments before `list_add_tail()` in the main implementation you link to first: —— `/**
 * list_add_tail - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it before
 *
 * Insert a new entry before the specified head.
 * This is useful for implementing queues.
 */`  —— Note the presence of 'new entry' multiple times.  Your code is not creating a new entry; it is trying to reuse an existing entry.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler excuse me again, but your last reasoning is totally not convincing! This is not about being wrong for million other kernel hackers. This is just a special case which others do not encounter yet! Hence, developing kernel means! :)

Comment: I admire your confidence, but remember that hubris leads to nemesis.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah! maybe you are true about about adding **new entry**; so must be somehow cautious about adding entries! lol :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux linked list does not support adding a node more than once. You can't add it twice to the same list, and you can't add it to two different lists.

Comment: is there any macro to make a copy instance?

Comment: I accept this answer, also thanks to @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @WillyCole You don't need a macro, you can just assign the `struct Node` value to another `struct Node`, for example `struct Node node1copy = node1;` `list_add_tail(&node1copy.myList, &plist);`. There is no need to do `INIT_LIST_HEAD(&node1copy.myList);` before adding it to the list, because the pointers in `node1copy.myList` will be overwritten by `list_add_tail` anyway.

Comment: @IanAbbott this is not permitted in C (that assignment is useful in C++ not in C)