# Player structure for a client server program

Tags: c, server, client, structure

I am implementing a version of anagram game in C. The program is of course multi-client server type.
So I have done almost all of the program but one thing. I want that my program to keep a history of each player that connects and plays the game in the server(when the client connects, one of the command line arguments is the username of the player).
I don't know exactly how I should do this.I mean what is the better way and more optimise way to implement this.
Do I do it with a list of players like this:

```c
typedef struct player
{
  char *username;
  int score;
} player_t;

typedef struct playerList
{
  int size;
  player_t* players_list;
} playerList_t;
```

Or is it better to do it like this:

```c
struct Player
{
  char *username;
  int score;
  Player *next;
};
```

Or is there another way better than these.
Of course I want to store this data into a file so that in case of having a server crashes, I don't loose the data.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend u using Linux kernel doubly linked-list, since its computation complexity is of O(1), and is extremely so fast.

u can find the mentioned user-space implementation in [Linux kernel doubly linked-list for user space](https://gist.github.com/roychen/1710968)

it takes some little time to understand it; but after that u will never implement an old-fashioned linked-list for ever. For an example u can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638304/adding-element-twice-into-linux-kernel-double-linked-list)

some of the advantages are:

- there is no need to implement your customized linked-list search, pull, push, etc. All of stuffs for doing list operations, such as search, replace, add, delete, combine, ... are all have been implemented in `list.h`
- the speed of list operations (computational complexity) of `list.h` is O(1) which means that it's not important how big your structure of your linked-list is; searching in the whole list does not grow when u enlarge your structure
- every time u want to add a new linked-list from scratch, i.e. a new linked-list based on a new `typedef struct`, u don't need to implement list operation (search, add, delete, ...) anymore. All things u need to do is just to add a new line `struct list_head myLinkedList` into your new structure. Then all of other jobs is done already :), which is a cool feature for code expansion

For your case, I recommend this:

```
#include "list.h"

struct player
{
    char *username;
    int score;
    struct list_head _list;
};

int main()
{
    LIST_HEAD(players_list);
    struct player p1 = {.username = "lolo", .score = 100};

    list_add_tail(&p1._list, &players_list);    

    struct player *iter;
    list_for_each_entry(iter, &players_list, _list)
    {
        printf("name = %s, data = %d\n", iter->username, iter->score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one question, how could I add more players to this list (I saw that you explained it in bullet points but could you give me an example please?) Because I only see head and not next or previous.

Comment: Also is there a function that allows me to add this playes in this list to a file for saving them?

Comment: @Mohammadreza use `list_add` or `list_add_tail` for adding new players; be aware that you have to allocate new memory before calling these functions; see my example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638304/adding-element-twice-into-linux-kernel-double-linked-list

Comment: @Mohammadreza what do u mean by saving in file _exactly_?! do u mean saving in a database? if so, u can use sqlite database which is a file-based db, i.e. all of your tables in the database are in just one file! using db can also prevents bugs such as file manipulation race condition, file recovery in case of error, and ....